# Use table metadata for select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large database and would like to select table names that have a certain column name. I have done something like this in MySQL, but can't find any info on SQL Server.

I want to do something like:

```
select [table] 
from [db] 
where table [has column 'classtypeid']
```

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ANSI information_schema views, this will also work in MySQL

```
select table_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where column_name = 'classtypeid'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
SELECT C.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
  INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = 'classtypeid'
  AND T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

---

**Edit**: Note that this will not list views based on any tables with that column. If you only query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS you will also get back views.